# Programming machxO2 from Linux

Tags: linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, fpga, lattice-diamond

I want to program a machxO2 CPLD. There is a driver in the kernel called "machxo2-spi". This driver contains the logic on how to program the machxO2.

I successfully have it loaded and everything. I've tried to program using the driver and I can see the data on the SPI bus. But I don't know what data I have to send to the machxO2. I've tried the bitstream, the jedec, and some other binary formats. Does anyone have any idea what the machxO2 expects as input for its SPI flash?